# Ajax request with will_paginate Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I've been reading through some posts on SO to see how others are handling this and the implementation I am using is almost there but fails after the third link requested. What happens is the page is reloaded as opposed to firing the ajax request. I have also removed Turbolinks but that hasn't made a difference.

This is my setup and I think the JS is failing somewhere. My jQuery is not that strong.

**Index.html.erb**

```
<div class="facebook_ajax">
  <%= render 'shared/posts' %>
</div>
```

**shared/_posts.html.erb**

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
<article class="post">
<%= image_tag('/assets/vandals_fb_profile.jpg') %>
<%= link_to 'Varsity Vandals', "https://www.facebook.com/VarsityVandals", target: 'blank' %>
<%= date_output(p.created_time) %>
  <figure>
    <% if p.large_image_url? %>
      <%= image_tag(p.large_image_url) %>
    <% end %>

    <% if p.video_url? %>
      <%= raw youtube_embed(p.video_url) %>
    <% end %>
  </figure>
  <p><%= p.message.gsub("\n", "<br>").html_safe %></p>
    <% if p.description? %>
      <p><%= p.description %></p>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'Read More', p.link %>
</article>
<hr/>
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate @posts, previous_label: '',  next_label: '', page_links: false %>
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$('.facebook_ajax').html("<%= escape_javascript(render("shared/posts"))%>")
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".facebook_ajax .pagination a").on("click", function(){
          $.getScript(this.href);
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
```

So when clicking the next link for the first time ajax request completes fine, but upon the third click the page reloads and the URL is changed to `?_=1399027258398&page=3`.

How can I combat this?

Answer (score 5):

Thought I would answer this so maybe it can help someone else, I had to delegate the event to a DOM element that was always there, so used the body tag for example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").on("click", '.facebook_ajax .pagination a', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $.getScript(this.href);
          return false;
        });
      });
```

My understanding that is once the first click is made you lose the oriiginal set of href's that where gathered

Good link [Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/)